# Agregar una calificación de estrellas con puro JavaScript/Html

Tags: javascript, html

Hola estoy haciendo un sistema de encuestas pero no logro implementar de manera correcta la parte del Rating de estrellas con HTML y JavaScript me estoy basando en esta pagina/source para realizar esto:

[Rateit.js](http://gjunge.github.io/rateit.js/examples/#ex_12)

Lo que intentado hasta ahorita o como tengo la parte de agregar mis preguntas es así:

```
function hacerPregunta(){

  p++;
  var tipo = $('#tipoPre').val();
  var pregunta = '<div class="row" id="preg'+p+'">'+
  '<div class="col-xs-12">'+
  '<div class="form-group"><div class="col-xs-11" style="padding: 0;">'+
  '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pregunta'+p+'" name="pregunta'+p+'" placeholder="¿Qué deséas preguntar? No olvides signos de puntuación ni ortografía."></div><div class="col-xs-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="padding: 7px; width: 30px;border-radius: 25px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="borrarPregunta('+p+');"><center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></center></button></div></div><br>';

  pregunta += '<input type="checkbox" id="obli'+p+'" name="obli'+p+'" value="1"> <label><strong>Esta pregunta es obligatoria de responder.</strong></label><br>';

  switch(tipo){

    case "4":

    opc++;
    pregunta += '<div class="row" id="mul'+p+opc+'"><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Opción" type="text" id="opcion'+p+opc+'" name ="opcion'+p+opc+'"></div><div class="col-xs-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="padding: 7px; width: 30px;border-radius: 25px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="borrarOpcion('+p+','+opc+');"><center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></center></button></div><br></div>';
    opc++;
    pregunta += '<div class="row" id="mul'+p+opc+'"><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Opción" type="text" id="opcion'+p+opc+'" name ="opcion'+p+opc+'"></div><div class="col-xs-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="padding: 7px; width: 30px;border-radius: 25px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="borrarOpcion('+p+','+opc+');"><center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></center></button></div><br></div>';

    pregunta += '<div id="opi'+p+'"></div>';
    pregunta += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="agregarOpcion('+p+', '+opc+');"><center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Agregar Opción</center></button>'
    pregunta += '<input type="hidden" id="tip'+p+'" name="tip'+p+'" value="'+tipo+'">';
    break;

    case "6":

    opc++;
    pregunta += '<div class="row" id="mul'+p+opc+'"><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Opción" type="text" id="opcion'+p+opc+'" name ="opcion'+p+opc+'"></div><div class="col-xs-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="padding: 7px; width: 30px;border-radius: 25px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="borrarOpcion('+p+','+opc+');"><center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></center></button></div></div>';
    opc++;
    pregunta += '<div class="row" id="mul'+p+opc+'"><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Opción" type="text" id="opcion'+p+opc+'" name ="opcion'+p+opc+'"></div><div class="col-xs-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="padding: 7px; width: 30px;border-radius: 25px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="borrarOpcion('+p+','+opc+');"><center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></center></button></div></div>';

    pregunta += '<div id="opi'+p+'"></div>';
    pregunta += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="agregarOpcion('+p+', '+opc+');"><center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Agregar Opción</center></button>'
    pregunta += '<input type="hidden" id="tip'+p+'" name="tip'+p+'" value="'+tipo+'">';
    break;

    case "7":

    opc++;
    pregunta += '<div class="row" id="mul'+p+opc+'"><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Opción" type="text" id="opcion'+p+opc+'" name ="opcion'+p+opc+'"></div><div class="col-xs-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="padding: 7px; width: 30px;border-radius: 25px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="borrarOpcion('+p+','+opc+');"><center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></center></button></div></div>';
    opc++;
    pregunta += '<div class="row" id="mul'+p+opc+'"><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Opción" type="text" id="opcion'+p+opc+'" name ="opcion'+p+opc+'"></div><div class="col-xs-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="padding: 7px; width: 30px;border-radius: 25px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="borrarOpcion('+p+','+opc+');"><center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></center></button></div></div>';

    pregunta += '<div id="opi'+p+'"></div>';
    pregunta += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="agregarOpcion('+p+', '+opc+');"><center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Agregar Opción</center></button>'
    pregunta += '<input type="hidden" id="tip'+p+'" name="tip'+p+'" value="'+tipo+'">';
    break;

    case 5: //Valoracion Star Rating
    opc++
    alert("es de valoracion");
    //pregunta += '<input type="range" value="5'+p+'" step="1" id="tip'+p+'" name="tip'+p+'">'
    //pregunta += '<input type="hidden" id="tip'+p+'" name="tip'+p+'" value="'+tipo+'">';
    //pregunta +='<div id="tip'+p+opc+'"></div>'
    break;

    default:
    pregunta = "";
    p--;
  }

  pregunta += '</div>'+
  '</div>'+
  '<br><br></div>';

  $("#cuantosP").val(p);
  $("#cuantosO").val(opc);
  $("#preguntas").append(pregunta);
}
```

Como pueden ver todo lo agrego con JavaScript y HTML pero esta parte del rating me esta dando problemas, solo seria cuestión de agregar un rate del 1 al 5 como lo es comúnmente, las preguntas o la parte del **Switch / Case** Utilizo un **Select** y bueno el resto se explica solo

Comment: podrías hacer funcional el ejemplo agregándolo en un html con el botón [<>] ?

Comment: mmm... y como mandaria llamar desde el switch de js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes un rating de estrellas ( 0 = sin calificar, 1 - 5 según el click )

Los id de radiobuttons y labels deben coincidir pero ser únicos así que tendrás que adaptarlos a tu código ( onda : `id="mul'+p+opc+'"` )

El javascript no es realmente necesario si va dentro de un form, es mas que nada para cambiar el texto que dice "sin calificar, 1 estrella, x estrellas", opcionalmente ahí podes meter un ajax que grabe el valor.

El funcionamiento es bastante simple:

- 6 radiobuttons con el mismo name y los posibles values ( 0 - 5 )
- los radiobuttons se esconden con css
- 6 labels, uno para cada radio button que contienen un svg, enlazados por el `for=id_del_radio_button`
- cada label que está inmediatamente después de un radio button pinta el svg de amarillo
- esto pinta todos los svg dentro de un label de amarillo
- cada label a la derecha de un radiobutton checked pinta su svg de blanco
- esto hace que las estrellas a la izquierda e inmediatamente a continuación del radio button checked sigan siendo amarillas, el resto se pinta de blanco
- por último hay un label para el radiobutton con value 0 ( sin calificar )

```js
// para todos los radiobutton rating agregar un on change
const changeRating = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=rating]');
changeRating.forEach((radio) => {
  radio.addEventListener('change', getRating);
});

// buscar el radiobutton checked y armar el texto con el valor ( 0 - 5 )
function getRating() {
  let estrellas = document.querySelector('input[name=rating]:checked').value;
  document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = (
    0 < estrellas ?
    estrellas + " estrella" + (1 < estrellas ? "s" : "") :
    "sin calificar"
  );

  // opcionalmente agregar un ajax para guardar el rating
}
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label.reset {
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
}

label.star {
  width: 30px;
  height: 27px;
}


/* ocultamos los radiobuttons */

input[name=rating] {
  display: none;
}


/* estrellas inmediatamente despues de un radiobutton van amarillas */

input[type=radio]+label.star svg path {
  fill: #fe0
}


/* estrellas a la derecha del radiobutton checked van blanco */

input[type=radio]:checked~label.star svg path {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- svg from https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo:Star*.svg -->

<input id=rating0 type=radio value=0 name=rating checked />

<label class=star for=rating1>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 275">
<path stroke="#605a00" stroke-width="15" 
  d="M150 25l29 86h90l-72 54 26 86-73-51-73 51 26-86-72-54h90z"/>
</svg>
</label>
<input id=rating1 type=radio value=1 name=rating />

<label class=star for=rating2>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 275">
<path stroke="#605a00" stroke-width="15"
 d="M150 25l29 86h90l-72 54 26 86-73-51-73 51 26-86-72-54h90z"/>
</svg>
</label>
<input id=rating2 type=radio value=2 name=rating />

<label class=star for=rating3>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 275">
<path stroke="#605a00" stroke-width="15"
 d="M150 25l29 86h90l-72 54 26 86-73-51-73 51 26-86-72-54h90z"/>
</svg>
</label>
<input id=rating3 type=radio value=3 name=rating />

<label class=star for=rating4>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 275">
<path stroke="#605a00" stroke-width="15"
 d="M150 25l29 86h90l-72 54 26 86-73-51-73 51 26-86-72-54h90z"/>
</svg>
</label>
<input id=rating4 type=radio value=4 name=rating />

<label class=star for=rating5>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 275">
<path stroke="#605a00" stroke-width="15"
 d="M150 25l29 86h90l-72 54 26 86-73-51-73 51 26-86-72-54h90z"/>
</svg>
</label>
<input id=rating5 type=radio value=5 name=rating />

<!-- por último el label del rating 0 ( sin calificar ) -->
<label class=reset for=rating0>reset</label>

<div id=texto>sin calificar</div>
```

Comment: Hola @alo pregunta, la parte del html me supongo que va en la parte de mi JS?

Comment: yup, armas el html como string dentro de tu js ( con el tema de los id para los radio button y el mismo para el label for )

Comment: hasta ahorita lo e implmentado pero no me marca la parte del clasificado y la primera estrella esta en negro xD, sabras porque pasa eso?

Comment: eps q no tome el css pueden ser las comillas, el resto habría que ver un ejemplo funcional de tu javascript dentro de un html

Comment: Hasta este punto creo que la respuesta fue respondida entonces para esta otra interrogante creo que preguntare de nuevo con un nuevo objetivo

Comment: puede que sea el orden de los input radio y los label